# Function only works on every second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Beginner to React here, currently learning how to build a shopping cart.

My **addToCart() function** has been passed as a function to an **add-to-cart button** onClick event handler, which is then supposed to update the cart array state via setCart.

The problem is, whenever I click the button (which is supposed to increment quantity), the cart array only updates on every second click (e.g. i click on Apple's add to cart, and cart remains at `{id: 1, quantity:2}` , and on the second click, it updates to `{id:1, quantity:3}`.

Also, when I click on add to cart for Orange (which has an id of 3), the first click will increment cart id 1 (e.g. i end up with `[{id: 1, quantity: 3}]`, while the second click gives `[{id: 1, quantity: 3}, {id: 3, quantity: 1}]`.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```js
const shoppingList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Apple", image: apple, price: 1.5 },
  { id: 2, name: "Pear", image: pear, price: 2.5 },
  { id: 3, name: "Orange", image: orange, price: 3.5 },
  { id: 4, name: "Banana", image: banana, price: 4.5 },
  { id: 5, name: "Watermelon", image: watermelon, price: 5.5 },
];

export default shoppingList;
```

```js
import shoppingList from "../Data/ShoppingList";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import AddToCart from "./AddToCart";

const ShoppingMenu = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([{ id: 1, quantity: 2 }]);

  function getItemID(id) {
    const itemID = shoppingList.find((shoppingItem) => id == shoppingItem.id);

    return itemID.id;
  }

  function addToCart(itemID) {
    const newCartItem = cart.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id == itemID);

    console.log({ newCartItem, cart });

    if (newCartItem === undefined) {
      const cartReplica = cart;
      setCart([...cartReplica, { id: itemID, quantity: 1 }]);
      console.log(cart);
    } else {
      console.log("exists");
      const cartReplica = cart;
      cartReplica.map((cartProduct) =>
        cartProduct.id == itemID
          ? setCart([{ ...cartProduct, quantity: cartProduct.quantity + 1 }])
          : cartProduct
      );
      console.log(cart);
    }
  }

  const mapShoppingMenu = shoppingList.map((shoppingItem) => {
    return (
      <div id={shoppingItem.id} className="item-card">
        <img src={shoppingItem.image} alt="" className="item-image" />
        <h2>{shoppingItem.name}</h2>
        <h3>${shoppingItem.price}</h3>
        <AddToCart />
        <button
          id={shoppingItem.id}
          onClick={(e) => {
            let itemID = getItemID(e.target.id);
            console.log(itemID);
            addToCart(itemID);
          }}
        >
          Add To Cart
        </button>
        {/* {console.log(cart)} */}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="shopping-list">{mapShoppingMenu}</div>;
};

export default ShoppingMenu;
```

Tried modifying addToCart, tried modifying the event handler for button..

Comment: Hey, can you create a codesandbox sample for me ? Thanks

Comment: you're referring to  to the `console.log(cart)`  at the end of addToCart to say that it doesn't works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code works fine. The problem is that you don't understand how the state is updated in a functional component.

`setCart` is asynchronous, meaning that the rest of your function will be executed before the value of `cart` changes. Why ? Because React doesn't immediately update the state. Instead, it schedules the update to be processed later.

So when you are calling `console.log(cart)` after `setCart`, the value logged into the console will be the previous value, not the new one. But if you render the value of `cart` you will see that it has been updated.

Here is a quick example to illustrate :
Let's say that i have a counter component

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1); // State update is scheduled asynchronously
    console.log(count); // This won't show the updated count immediately
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If i click on "Increment", the logged value will be 0, but the value rendered will be 1, because when `console.log` is called, `count` hasn't been updated yet, but a few ms laters the component will be rerendered with the new value.

I know that this can be a challenging topic for beginners in React, so if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask !

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot now. Thank you for combing through my spaghetti code and giving a concise answer!

Comment: @ka1233 Well explained by Florent! Maybe consider using `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);` instead of `setCount(count + 1);` as the new value of count depends on the previous one. The result will most times be the same, but in some cases the method without the callback-function can be buggy due to side effects of asynchronous execution. By the way you can use `setCount(prevCount => { const newCount = prevCount + 1; console.log(newCount); return newCount; });` To log the change immediately in the console.

Comment: An example for my comment above would be, if you click the button one more time before the recent `setCount(count + 1)` call updated `count` (yes, you would have to click very fast), the last call of `setCount(count + 1)` would read the old value of `count` and therefore `count` would only be increased by 1 instead of 2.